# How to fix video playback showing green screen with just audio?

Tags: 12.04, video

When I attempt to view a video file, I get a solid green screen with audio, regardless of the application or file format. This happens with `.mp4`, `.gp`, and `.dv` files.

I am unable to use live web cam with Skype, also getting a solid green screen. I am using 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 on an iMac.

There is no problem viewing videos on the Internet, i.e. YouTube, etc., and the files I upload to YouTube play normally. I only have problems viewing local files. I do not use VLC Media Player. How do I go about changing the hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 8):

I have tried [Mukund](https://askubuntu.com/a/233525/955229)'s answer and same other answers and its working, but i am just extending the answer that below follow is worked for me.

1. Go to **Tools → Preferences**.
2. Select **Input/Codes → Hardware-accelerated decoding**. In this, select the **Disable** option.

After restart the VLC and its should work. I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 6):

While the root of the problem is likely hidden in your video drivers, a quick fix is to just disable hardware acceleration in Flash. You might experience a slight decrease in performance, but you'll actually get video working again without going to too much trouble.

**In VLC Media Player:**

1. Click on Tools --> Preferences
2. Click on the Video tab
3. Uncheck the "Accelerated video output (Ovelay) box.
4. Save these settings and it should work immediately.

**For Youtube videos you could do this:**

1) Right click on youtube video.

2) Go to settings.

3)  UNCHECK the 'Enable hardware acceleration' tickbox.

4) Refeshed and works fine now.

I also recommend you to install/reinstall your video/display driver.

Answer (score 0):

For me the above answer didn't work, but as I figured out, in my case the problem with green blinking of the screen were caused by enabled transparency *(I am using a tiling WM with Compton which enables transparency for inactive windows)*.

So I could disable it. The other solution, that I gone with, is running VLC in a separate XServer, like `xinit  /usr/bin/vlc ./MyVideo.mkv -- :1 vt8`.