# Opening mp4 file with videos shows a green screen with audio

Tags: sound, video, files, multimedia

I have an .mp4 file that I'm trying to play with `videos` (the preinstalled video player on Ubuntu 18).

I get the audio and a green screen.  No video.

The closest thing I could find relating to this problem was [How to fix video playback showing green screen with just audio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233510/how-to-fix-video-playback-showing-green-screen-with-just-audio)

I don't use VLC though so none of the answers were of any help.

I also tried running the same video with Firefox and it worked fine, so I'm quite sure it's a problem with Videos itself.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is probably not the answer you want, but - the problem will probably not be present in VLC if you install & try it. The bundled "videos" app is quite basic, and it also doesn't get as much attention in terms of bug fixes and improvements ans VLC does.

Comment: @JonasCz-ReinstateMonica I'll probably end up installing VLC anyway. I used to use it on Windows, and absolutely loved it.  I was worried something had gone wrong with my OS, like the drivers hadn't installed properly or something, (I only installed it as main last night, and I'm only used to running it as a VM).  I wasn't expecting it to be such a difficult problem to be honest.